AWS Amplify getCurrentUser in a nextJS server component
I am trying to write a server side component in NextJS, that relies on knowing the authenticated user.
According to the docs, this is achieved using the getCurrentUser function. The problem is that when called in a server component, it fails with the error 'user must be authenticated to call this API'. The user is definitely authenticated, which I have confirmed by changing my component to be client a component, in which case it works fine.
I am able to call fetchAuthSession from the server component, which works, but does not give me the user details that getCurrentUser would.
